# HLS - #EXTINF value wrong for last segment?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I have run into an issue in which the **#EXTINF** value for the last TS segment in my *.m38u* manifest file is incorrect. The video files I am encoding often have a millisecond remainder on the end (I.E. 1:00.245). My segment size is 10 seconds but when I encode the file it is basically dividing the duration by 10 and the lsat segment is a tiny millisecond segment but it's **#EXTINF** value is display 10 seconds when it should be 0.255. This is causing issues because players reading this manifest think that the clip is 70 seconds long instead of 60. My manifest looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_2000000_0.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_1.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_2.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_3.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_4.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_5.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_6.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_7.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_8.ts

#EXTINF:10,

outdoor_activities_hls_layer0_1000000_9.ts

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Any idea on how to address this issue?

Comment: how are you encoding this? mediastreamsegmenter on a mac? ffmpeg? m3u8-segmenter on linux? all of them produce slightly different .m3u8 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Rhzoet by design whatever segment length is set in the preset configuration it will use that length for each segment..even if the segment is not 10 seconds it rounds up. Not sure if this is the same for all HLS encoders though..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm being obtuse, but the answer seems very simple: change your playlist file to have the correct time on the last EXTINF tag.